# 403 error when try to pull code from aws repository

Tags: git, amazon-web-services

when try to pull from repository to local i am getting below error, but in other computer able pull with my AWS credentials, but here it is not asking for aws username and password any solution?

fatal: unable to access 'repository name': The requested URL returned error: 403

Answer (score 0):

Then double-check the output of

```
git config --global credential.helper
```

For HTTPS URL, it is likely to cache your old credentials.

If, for instance, the credential helper is manager-core, try

```
printf "host=remoteHost\nprotocol=http"|git credential-manager-core get
```

Replace `RemoteHost` by the AWS server name.

But if, [as commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553931/403-error-when-try-to-pull-code-from-aws-repository/71554584?noredirect=1#comment126465869_71554584), the help is an AWS command, then simply do a [`aws codecommit credential-helper get`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codecommit/credential-helper/erase.html) to confirm the wrong credentials are cached.

If so, `aws codecommit credential-helper erase`.

Comment: for first command getting this  !aws codecommit credential-helper $@, don't know how to proceed further

Comment: @kumar Thank you for this feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: tried above commands but no use getting same 403 error

Comment: @kumar Then you need `aws codecommit credential-helper store` in order to store the right credentials.

Comment: first step if i use git pull, it needs to ask username and password but it is throwing 403

Comment: @kumar Did that password changed before? Changed recently? Or did you activate 2FA (multi-factor authentication: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/secure-aws-codecommit-with-multi-factor-authentication/), in which case you would need a token in place of your AWS password. Or an IAM account dedicated for Git access: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/security-iam.html. Or even https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/temporary-access.html.